# Downgrade DNN Database Version from SQL Server Version 12 to 11

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke

I need to Downgrade my DNN Database from SQL Server Version 12 to 11, i know that i need to generate scripts and run this script on other sql instance but i am facing with an error that i do not know how to solve it.

here is the error messages:

```
Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 135
INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify
that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns     and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY     constraint "FK_ContentItems_Tags_Taxonomy_Terms". The conflict occurred in database "mehrabaddb", table "dbo.Taxonomy_Terms", column 'TermID'.
Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Constraint 'FK_ContentItems_Tags_Taxonomy_Terms' does not exist.
Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY    constraint "FK_FolderPermission_Users". The conflict occurred in database "mehrabaddb", table "dbo.Users", column 'UserID'.
Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Constraint 'FK_FolderPermission_Users' does not exist.
Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Profile_Users". The     conflict occurred in database "mehrabaddb", table "dbo.Users", column 'UserID'.
Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Constraint 'FK_Profile_Users' does not exist.Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.
The module 'AddEventLog' depends on the missing object 'dbo.AddEventLogType'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'AddEventLog' depends on the missing object 'dbo.AddEventLogConfig'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'AddTab' depends on the missing object 'dbo.BuildTabLevelAndPath'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'aspnet_Membership_CreateUser' depends on the missing object 'dbo.aspnet_Users_CreateUser'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'aspnet_Profile_DeleteProfiles' depends on the missing object 'dbo.aspnet_Users_DeleteUser'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'aspnet_Profile_SetProperties' depends on the missing object 'dbo.aspnet_Users_CreateUser'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
```

Comment: This output is not very helpfull without the instert script... Try to only run the first insert and see what it outputs, and when youve got that right it will probably all fix itself.

Comment: actually i find simple solution : Find and Replace SET ANSI_PADDING OFF with SET ANSI_PADDING ON

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution: Find and Replace SET ANSI_PADDING OFF with SET ANSI_PADDING ON